# HTML&CSS regulate the height of the content

Tags: html, css

i'm starting over with html and i have a question that i'm stuck on.
I am building a store. All pages have the same structure: Header, Main, Footer.
I want that the footer is always at the bottom of a page. I have already tried with position: absolute; bottom:0;. But that doesn't work, because the main-part is only as big as the content.
On other pages I have the problem that the content is bigger than the main.
What can I do to avoid these problems.

#edit
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKFud.jpg)
Here you can see, the content is bigger than de main. How can I solve this problem

Comment: you can used position: fixed for footer if you want it to be sticky, ie stay there irrespective of scroll position or height of viewport. Always put a margin bottom on the main to compensate for the footer height.

Comment: If the Main doesn't have enough content at that time you have to show footer in bottom of the screen right?

Comment: yes, Multani Sadik

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox and create your layout like this: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/simonxabris/pen/rNyNoLg)

Putting `flex-grow: 1` on the `main` element ensures that it will always stretch the available space. Notice that you have to make sure that the body stretches the full height of the screen for this to work. That's what `height: 100vh` does.

If you're unfamiliar with flexbox here's a great guide that I always come back to when I'm not sure about something: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should make a sticky footer

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

And then fix your footer if it necessary

Answer (score 0):

hi there it's so simple you can use this and you will get your footer stick at the bottom:

```
  body{
       min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
   }
   footer{
       margin-top: auto;
   }
```

using flex-box like that make sur this works no matter what and using margin-top : auto it will force the footer to stay at bottom.